# How to put unsigned float into ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, unsigned

I'm trying to handle unsigned primitives number with `ByteBuffer`.

I can handle (put into `ByteBuffer`) unsigned byte/short/int.
For example, the code to handle unsigned int:

```
m_buf.putInt(nOffset, (int) (0xFFFFFFFF & number.longValue()));
```

but, when I want to do the same for unsigned float:

```
m_buf.putFloat(nOffset, (float) (0xFFFFFFFF & number.doubleValue()));
```

I'm getting compiler error: "The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) int, double"

So - How can I handle get and set unsigned float number with `ByteBuffer`?

Thanks

Comment: There's not really any agreed-upon definition of an unsigned float at all.

Comment: you are right,
after check with cpp project - there isn't unsigned float... :)

Comment: This question really doesn't make any sense.  Java doesn't have unsigned types at all (unless you count `char`) - and I'm not aware of any language that has unsigned floats.  I'm trying to imagine what an unsigned float would possibly be - the idea just doesn't exist.

Comment: @DavidWallace, I would imagine that the sign bit would be used as part of the mantissa or exponent.

Comment: Yeah, we might imagine that.  The question still makes no sense.  "I'm trying to handle unsigned primitives number" is equivalent to "I'm trying to herd unicorns".  We can imagine what those unicorns might look like, but what's the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEEE 754 floating point representation has 1 bit reserved for the sign. There is no alternative representation that uses this bit as part of the mantissa or exponent. In other words, there is no "unsigned float".

If all you want to do is to make sure you don't put any negative numbers in the buffer, just do

```
m_buf.putFloat(nOffset, Math.abs(number.floatValue()));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use bitwise `&` with floating point numbers. Try this:

```
m_buf.putFloat(nOffset, Float.valueOf(0xFFFFFFFF & number));
```